# Textures or pictures as background for a table.

Tags: tables, graphics

I wonder how I can set a texture or a picture in the background of a table. I have tried to google it but I haven't found any satisfactory answer :-(

I try to explain better: I know that it is possible to put a background color in a table just by nesting a tabular environment into a `\colorbox` command, e.g. the command

```
\colorbox{COLOR}{\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}}
```

creates a tabular with a COLOR background.

Now, I wish to do the same, but instead of using a background color, I want use a background image or a background texture (e.g a "zebra"-like texture, etc). Is it possible? Does it exist some command that I can use in the same way as `\colorbox`, e.g.

```
\some_command{IMAGE}{\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}}
```

that puts IMAGE as background to the tabular? If not, how I can accomplish my goal? I hope my request is clear... :-S

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Also, you can format [inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) by using backticks ` and [blocks of code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) by indenting four spaces (or highlighting the code and clicking on the `{}` button in the editor). This helps to make the posts clearer and easier to read.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one option using the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package in combination with the also powerful [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). Using a style you can specify the table preamble, the image and possibly other attributes:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
bgtable/.style={
enhanced,
colframe=red!50!black,
colbacktitle=Salmon!30,
coltitle=black,
center title,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
watermark graphics=#1,
watermark opacity=0.3,
nobeforeafter}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[bgtable=mushrooms.jpg,tabularx*={}{XXXXX},title=My table,watermark stretch=1.00]
One & Two & Three & Four & Five\\
\midrule
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
\end{tcolorbox}

\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[bgtable=ctanlion.png,tabularx*={}{XXXXX},title=My table,watermark stretch=1.00,width=8cm,watermark opacity=0.3]
One & Two & Three \\
\midrule
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you prefer a more sober style:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
bgtable/.style={
freelance,
frame code={\draw[ultra thick] (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east);}
center title,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
watermark graphics=#1,
watermark stretch=1.00,
watermark opacity=0.3,
arc=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
nobeforeafter}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[bgtable=papiro.png,tabularx*={}{XXXXX},watermark opacity=0.6]
One & Two & Three & Four & Five\\
\midrule
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tcolorbox}

\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[bgtable=papiro.png,tabularx*={}{XXXXX},title=My table,watermark stretch=1.00,width=8cm,watermark opacity=0.6]
One & Two & Three \\
\midrule
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A third example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
bgtable/.style={
freelance,
frame code={}
center title,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
fontupper=\bfseries\sffamily,
watermark graphics=#1,
watermark stretch=1.00,
watermark opacity=1,
arc=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
nobeforeafter,
coltext=white}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[bgtable=drops.jpeg,tabularx*={\arrayrulecolor{white}}{XXXXX}]
One & Two & Three & Four & Five\\
\midrule
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 \\
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: I got an error: Unknown option `most' for package `tcolorbox'

Comment: @schmendrich you need an up-dated version of the package; in my system (TeX Live2013) I have `tcolorbox.sty    2013/07/29 version 2.50 text color boxes`.

Comment: Wow, that is fast development. I have version 2.2 and it is only 2 month older.

Comment: @schmendrich yes, the author has been very active. Newer versions offer a lot of new useful features.

Comment: That's a very nice looking solution!

Comment: Very nice solution!!!

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\bottominset{%
\color{magenta}%
\Huge%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
This & is & a \\
\hline
test & of & tabular\\
\hline
inset & into & graphics\\
\hline
is & this & what \\
\hline
 is & & needed?\\
\hline
& & today\\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}{%
\scalebox{.66}{\includegraphics{sbs2}}%
}{1.4in}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]