# Symbol or image behind heading

Tags: graphics, symbols, embedding

I would like to insert/embed symbols/images behind a heading.

Do you know, if that can be done?

Comment: Maybe this post could give you some ideas.  Gonzalo Medina used `tcolorbox` to put a picture behind a tabular environment.  I am not sure how you would extrapolate this to section headings (that is get an image behind the heading).  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128231/textures-or-pictures-as-background-for-a-table

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I think the user wants the heading and then a picture behind the text as in a water mark type look.

Comment: Does the link I posted capture the idea but in a different context then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible solution using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) (make the adjustments that best suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
bgtable/.style={
freelance,
frame code={}
center title,
left=0pt,
right=0pt,
top=0pt,
bottom=0pt,
watermark graphics=bricks.jpeg,
watermark stretch=1.00,
watermark opacity=0.7,
arc=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
nobeforeafter}
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\Large\bfseries\thesection\hspace{1em}}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[bgtable]
      \thesection\hspace{1em}\hangindent\wd0\strut#1\strut%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[bgtable]
      \strut#1\strut
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{4.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section{Test numbered section}
\lipsum[4]
\section*{Test unnumbered section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Test numbered section with a long title; in fact, it spans two lines}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

My example only deals with `\section` and `\section*`, but the same idea can be easily adapted to other sectional units.

In the comments, it has been required to add an image to the left of the titles; in this case, there's no need for the `tcolorbox` package and one can use `\llap` and some boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\SecImage{%
\llap{\makebox[3em][l]{%
  \raisebox{-.65\totalheight}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=2em]{example-grid-100x100pt}%
    }%
  }%
}%
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\Large\bfseries\thesection\hspace{1em}}%
    \SecImage\thesection\hspace{1em}\hangindent\wd0\strut#1\strut%
  }
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {\SecImage#1}

\begin{document}

\section{Test numbered section}
\lipsum[4]
\section*{Test unnumbered section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Test numbered section with a long title; in fact, it spans two lines}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I figured you would answer this question.

Comment: @dustin yes; the code in the other answer was almost ready to transfer here :-)

Comment: @Stefan no; no known conflicts. As long as you have an up-dated LaTeX system, my code works as expected. Some questions for you: Compile my example code *as is* (replacing `bricks.jpeg` with one of your own images) Do you get errors? If not, what exactly is the error message you get when incorporating my code into your document?

Comment: @Stefan surely yes, but I don't quite understand what you want. Where exactly should the image appear?

Comment: @Stefan so the image should start a little left from the left margin and span the whole text width area, as in my answer (but starting a little to the left)?

Comment: @Stefan please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you want?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it. I will be erasing other comments shortly.