# How to add a background image to a tabular?

Tags: tabularx

I want to add an image as the background of a whole table, and the background image is scaled to the actual size of the table.

Something like in the following example would be perfect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}

  \AddBackground{image-path} 

    1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
    7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128231/textures-or-pictures-as-background-for-a-table